# Use current AutoFilter to load Data-Validation

Tags: excel, excel-2010, validation, autofilter, vba

I have  a situation where i am using two Data-Validation cells which are loaded with data from one column (each) from the data table.

#### Table

market; suprv; store; ....

#### Data-Validation

- **cellDV1** - Unique Values from **Table[market]**
- **cellDV2** - Unique Values from **Table[suprv]**

Both **cellDV1** & **cellDV2** are preloaded with their respective unique values when the user views the worksheet.

When the user selects a value from **cellDV1** then it AutoFilters the **Table** with the selected value.  I then want to reload **cellDV2** with the refined results visible in **Table**.

Problem i am having is that it is loading all of the Unique Values from that column/field in the Table and not the AutoFiltered results.

#### Usage:

```
LoadDataValidation Range("Table[suprv]"), Range("cellRange")
```

#### LoadDataValidation:

```
Dim str As String
str = DistinctValues(srcrng)
Dim val As Validation
Set val = Range(destrng.Address).Validation
val.Delete
val.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, str
```

Any ideas, how to only select the Filtered results instead of the whole dataset in the Table?

Comment: I haven't worked with Tables very much, but can you apply the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` property to the Range ... So `Range("Table[suprv]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` as your first argument in `LoadDataValidation`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman ill try that out.  I havent had any luck with SpecialCells in the past, seem a tad inconsistent in some situations, which i seem just about hit 70-90% of the time ;)

Comment: `SpecialCells` can be VERY useful, if you understand how they work, what situations to use them in and when to error-trap them

Comment: @ScottHoltzman go head and post that as an answer so i can uptick and check it

Comment: Done GoldBishop. Good to know it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Tables very much, but can you apply the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`property to the Range

So `Range("Table[suprv]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` as your first argument in LoadDataValidation